# How to select most recent record while using self join in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+----------+
| Item Code | Vendor Code | Direct Cost |   Date   |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+----------+
|      6994 |        1441 |        3.86 | 20150512 |
|      6994 |        1441 |        3.86 | 20150910 |
|      6994 |        1441 |        4.62 | 20160425 |
|      6994 |        1441 |        4.62 | 20161017 |
|      6994 |        1441 |        4.05 | 20170330 |
|      6994 |        1441 |        4.10 | 20170624 |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+----------+
```

I am creating a view and I have joined 2 tables PO Header and PO Details, so in this example above I just need 1 line result because Item Code and Vendor Code is repeating, I have achieved this by using the self join on the table but the main requirement is to pick 1 line with most recent date record i.e. 20170624 and Direct Cost is = 4.10

Please see my code below.

`l.AUDTDATE` is the date column but not in the date format, so I have converted it into date format and in descending order but I am struggling in getting the 1 line with the most recent date.

Thanks

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    dbo.NavMdItem.nav_item_code,
    dbo.NavMdVendor.nav_vendor_code, 
    l.ORDERUNIT AS uom, 
    '' AS variant_code, 
    h.POCURR AS currency_code, 
    '1' AS minimum_qty,
    l.UNITCOST AS direct_unit_cost, 
    SUBSTRING(CAST(h.DAYENDDATE AS VARCHAR(50)), 7, 2) + '/' +
        SUBSTRING(CAST(h.DAYENDDATE AS VARCHAR(50)), 5, 2) + '/' +
        SUBSTRING(CAST(h.DAYENDDATE AS VARCHAR(50)), 0, 5) AS starting_date,
    l.DAYENDSEQ,
    CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(l.AUDTDATE AS VARCHAR(50)), 106) AS date 
FROM
    skh.POPORAH AS h 
INNER JOIN 
    skh.POPORAL AS l ON h.PORAHSEQ = l.PORAHSEQ AND h.DAYENDSEQ = l.DAYENDSEQ 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.NavMdItem ON l.ITEMNO = dbo.NavMdItem.item_long_code COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.NavMdVendor ON h.VENDOR = dbo.NavMdVendor.vendor_short_code COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS 
WHERE
    (NOT (l.ITEMNO LIKE 'MISC')) 
    AND (l.ITEMEXISTS = 1)
    AND (dbo.NavMdVendor.entity_code = 10) 
    AND (h.DAYENDDATE > 20150101) 
    AND (dbo.NavMdItem.nav_item_code = 6499) 
    AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1
          FROM skh.POPORAL AS f
          WHERE (DAYENDSEQ = l.DAYENDSEQ) 
            AND (DAYENDSEQ <= l.DAYENDSEQ)) < 2)
ORDER BY 
    l.AUDTDATE DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to group by item code and vendor code and select MAX date.

Is there zero chance of having two on the same date?

UPDATE:

Here is some code that will do what you're wanting. Notice I assumed valid datetime data in the [aud_date] column.

```
CREATE TABLE #Stuff(
    item_code int
    ,vendor_code int
    ,direct_cost money
    ,aud_date datetime
    )

INSERT #Stuff VALUES (6994,1441,3.86,'2015-05-12 11:32:12')
INSERT #Stuff VALUES (6994,1441,3.86,'2015-09-10 05:11:00')
INSERT #Stuff VALUES (6994,1441,4.62,'2016-04-25 19:43:43')
INSERT #Stuff VALUES (6994,1441,4.62,'2016-10-17 11:12:13')
INSERT #Stuff VALUES (6994,1441,4.05,'2017-03-30 01:02:03')
INSERT #Stuff VALUES (6994,1441,4.10,'2017-06-24 12:12:12')

SELECT
    *
FROM 
    #Stuff
WHERE
    aud_date = (
        SELECT MAX(aud_date)
        FROM
            #Stuff
        WHERE
            item_code = item_code
        AND
            vendor_code = vendor_code
        GROUP BY
            item_code, vendor_code
    )

DROP TABLE #Stuff
```

Comment: Yes, it's a possibility.

Comment: You'll need to switch to datetime for your data type if you only want the latest record of two occurring on the same day.

Comment: That I have already done, as you can see I have used Convert function on column l.AUDTDATE but when I use self join it's picking a random value which is an old date.

Comment: if l.AUDTDATE is a date not datetime, your convert is just going to make it something like '2018-01-24 00:00:00'. What is the actual value stored in AUDTDATE? If it's a datetime, why are you casting it to a varchar and then converting it?

Comment: l.AUDTDATE has string datatype but when I was trying to convert it into datetime, it wasn't working, so I have converted it into varchar first and then into datetime which worked well but not able to get recent date.

Comment: I don't have enough information, sorry. Your query does not return the results you used as an example. The number of columns in the example does not match the number of items in the SELECT, for example. I have no idea what you're trying to do with your query, but I will update my answer with SQL that will give you what you want from your sample data set. You should be able to figure it out from there.